# Python - Abort current function without stop running tkinter mainloop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm new in Python, if it is possible to realize abort immediately as in the following situation.

Condition : 2 button : `Start` & `Abort`

When I press the `Start` button, the code should start to do a function, and if I press `Abort` button, the function will stop immediately no matter what it did, and become initial state (before pressing the `Start` button).

Besides, I know "signal.CTRL_C_EVENT / CTRL_BREAK_EVENT", but it will close all code including `Tkinter mainloop`.

Comment: What have you tried, why did this attempt fail? Aka a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I imaging you would need a combination of threading and a True/False variable that can be updated by tkinter and read by the function. Is this function a loop of some kind or just executing some series of commands that may take time?

Comment: I have many test items, and it can be choose by check button, and every test item has own function, like send commands, control equipment, read feedback and delay...etc

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Here is an example using a looping method within a class. This works if you have some kind of function to run in a loop. You just need to put the check for running where its most effective at breaking the loop.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Example(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.running = False
        tk.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.start).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="abort", command=self.abort).pack()

    def start(self):
        self.running = True
        self.running_loop()

    def abort(self):
        self.running = False

    def running_loop(self):
        if self.running == True:
            print("running")
            self.after(100, self.running_loop)
        else:
            print("stopped")


app = Example()
app.mainloop()
```

If you are doing something more complicated like needing to run some complicated query then you may need to do this with multi-threading in order to keep the process separate from Tkinter. The reason for this is Tkinter is a single threaded event driven program and cannot multi-thread itself. So we need to manage things that need to be aborted with threading. That is a little more complicated and maybe case by case need so I would need to know more about what it is you are attempting to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot, what I want to do is a little complicated. For example, I have 3 test items, the first test is to time.sleep(10), then second test is to communicate with product via pyserial, and third test is to control instrument like power supply, spectrum...etc.

Comment: When I test 1st item, if I want to abort this at any time, if it possible when python is running time.sleep(10)?

Comment: Don't use sleep with Tkinter. They do not play well. Use `after()` instead.

Comment: OK ! Thanks a lot !